# DynamoDB : Is it possible to query by hash and range without creating two tables?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If I want to create a DynamoDB table with `ItemId` and `BatchId` and I want to be able to query by `ItemId` and `BatchId` do I have to create two tables:

```
Table1: Hash-ItemId Range-BatchId
Table2: Hash-BatchId Range-ItemId
```

Or is there a way to use secondary indexes to avoid duplication?

Comment: A few questions: what exactly do you mean by `avoid duplication`? Does an `ItemId` correspond to a bunch of `BatchId`s?

Comment: Yes each itemID will be in multiple batches. And each batchId will have multiple itemIDs

Comment: you mean that a) a query by itemId should result in multiple item+batch elements. and b) a query by batch should result in multiple batch+item elements? (item+batch=batch+item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a global secondary index on Table1 with BatchId as hash key?

Reopen because I think this answer is useful. Please correct me instead of closing the answer. @rfornal @Devin.

Hey @Nickolay I saw your comments below. Range key of base table CAN be used as hash key of GSI.

To prove that I created a table like this:

Base table: HashKey: hash + RangeKey:range

GSI table: HashKey: range + Rangekey: hash

Inserted some keys:
[image]

query base table:
[image]

query gsi:
[image]

Comment: I thought I saw somewhere in the documentation that to perform Query operation you must have range key (struggling to find it right now).Then wouldn't I have to duplicate the ItemId as secondary global index since I can't make the range key a global secondary index? `Table1: Hash-BatchId Range-ItemId SecondaryGlobalIndex-ItemId` If we can query a table that has a Hash and GlobalSecondary Index (without range key) then this solution would in fact work

Comment: This looks like a comment, rather than an attempt at answering the question.